# Qt- change QStringList element

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have *groupProfpic* as QStringList. I'v added the same photo to all of element

```
for (int k=0 ; k<4 ; ++k)
    groupProfpic.append(":/images/person.png");
```

If each person has profile picture ,default profile picture(*":/images/person.png"*) will replace to his/her profile picture.

```
   for (int i=0 ; i<nicknamesList.size() ; ++i)
        {
            query1.prepare("SELECT profpic FROM muc_members WHERE nickname=? LIMIT 4");
            query1.addBindValue(nicknamesList[i]);
            query1.exec();
            if(query1.next())
            {
                groupProfpic[i] = query1.value(0).toString();
            }
```

but it's not working. How to fix it?

Comment: *it's not working.* What are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check return value of QSqlQuery::exec():

```
if (query1.exec()) {
    //do your work
    //and see what you have
    qDebug() << "Image path:" << query1.value(0).toString(); 
}
else {
    //you have an error
}
```